# Modificar algoritmo para dar formato a teléfonos

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy nuevo en programación, e hice este pequeño programa que se encarga de "darle formato a un número telefónico", es decir, ingresas una cadena de números y lo retornará con guiones cada dos números.

El código funciona, pero quería saber si hay alguna manera de hacer que el programa haga el mismo procedimiento sin necesidad de hacer todo lo que hice, ¿hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo para que sea más corto y que al final haga lo mismo? No importa que la solución sea completamente diferente.

Cualquier ayuda o idea es completamente bienvenida, gracias.

```
private void formatoTelefono()
    {
        StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder();        
        StringBuilder cadenaFormato = new StringBuilder();
        String temp = "";               

        cadena.append(textoTelefono.getText());

         System.out.println(cadena.length());

        for(int i = 0; i != cadena.length(); i++)
        {
            cadenaFormato.append(cadena.charAt(i));

            if(isPar(i) == false)
            {
                cadenaFormato.append('-');
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }        
        cadenaFormato.deleteCharAt(cadenaFormato.lastIndexOf("-"));

        textoTelefonoFormato.setText(cadenaFormato.toString());
    }


private boolean isPar(int numero)
    {
        if(numero % 2 != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private void botonFormatoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        formatoTelefono();
    }
```

Comment: Hola no controlas el caso en que la cadena ingresada ya tenga formato. O, de que su formato de ingreso sea parcial o no corresponda con el esperado. Tu código todavía necesita algo más, antes de pensar en optimizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un contador en el que se almacena el numero de dígitos, cuando éste sea 2, que añada un guión (y se vuelve a reiniciar el contador).

```
private void formatoTelefono() {
    String cadena = textoTelefono.getText();
    StringBuilder cadenaFormato = new StringBuilder();
    int digits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if (digits == 2) {
            cadenaFormato.append("-");
            digits = 0;
        }
        cadenaFormato.append(cadena.charAt(i));
        digits++;
    }

    textoTelefonoFormato.setText(cadenaFormato.toString());
}
```